# Filter Out Duplicate Entries from Textbox with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a script that would filter out duplicate entries on line-by-line basis in a form textbox. I'm learning more & more about the array_unique() function & arrays in general, but I haven't yielded any success.

To explain it better, I have a 'textarea' that I will be using as the input in a form. Each new line break will be treated as if it were an array string, of which I would then submit it to my PHP script to then use the array_unique() function to filter out the lines that are the same.

I'm fairly new to PHP so the attempts I've made, have only resulted in duplicate lines with only the word, 'Array' being repeated.

Comment: can you post what you have tried so that we can give suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can store each line in an array using explode function, if you are using `<br />` tag to insert new line, then use `<br />` as delimiter or `\n` if you are using `\n` to insert new line:

```
$arr = explode('<br />', inputString);
```

Then to remove duplicate values from array use `array_unique();`

```
$arr = array_unique($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$unique = array_unique(explode("\n", $_POST['textarea']));
```